# Ошибка Insert в коде

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите мне исправить данную ошибку
и объяснить в чем дело.

Ошибка:

Ни одна из перегрузок метода `Insert` не принимает `7` аргументов

Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty && textBox2.Text != String.Empty && textBox3.Text != String.Empty && textBox4.Text != String.Empty && maskedTextBox1.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        tablTableAdapter.Insert(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value), Convert.ToDouble(maskedTextBox1.Text), textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value));
        MessageBox.Show("Добавлено!");
        Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Не все поля были заполнены!");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нельзя вставлять все поля за раз и вначале указывается индекс. И метод insert надо переприсваивать.
Например: `tablTableAdapter=tablTableAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),textBox1.Text);
tablTableAdapter=tablTableAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value),textBox2.Text);`
и т.д.

Comment: советую ознакомится https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: теперь ругается на insert не принимает "2"

Comment: ругается не принимает "2" инсерт

Comment: Лучше почитай справку которою я скинул. У меня нет твого уода, чтоб узнать, что у тебя там случилось

Comment: При чем здесь `String.Insert` когда речь идет об адаптере?